# To install co-exist Ubuntu 12.04 with Windows 7

Tags: multi-boot, ubuntu-12.04

Recently I have had Windows 7 re-installed on my laptop. Now the layout of partitions and volumes

```
=============Primary=======================================
Partition0\system reserved: size 100Mb
Partition1\VolumeC: [NTFS, size 60Gb] - Windows System
Partition2\VolumeD: [NTFS, size 39Gb] - (empty)

=============Extended======================================
Partition3\Logical VolumeE: [NTFS, size 100GB] - Programs
Partition3\Logical VolumeF: [NTFS, size 100GB] - Files
```

As you might know that I'd reserved `Partition2` for Linux Ubuntu 12.04.

My question is: would it be just so easy to boot system with Ubuntu 12.04 CD to install on `Partition2`? Do I have to install grub on `Partition2` as well for dual boot?

Note that I'd like Windows loader in MBR. I can foresee that I need to run bcdedit in Windows 7 to add entry for Ubuntu. But I might miss something I don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you install boot system on your second drive or other than first drive ( that windows's boot is ) your system will boot with your windows boot and you could easily add the ubuntu to your boot menu with `EasyBCD` .

I'm afraid that If you want to install ubuntu on your second partition you have to change it's format to `ext4` and windows doesn't recognize this format and maybe you can not access the partitions after second partition (third or fourth or ... ) in Windows.

Comment: Hmm...but why does file system of the second primary partition do with that of the third or fourth? May I just leave them there?

Comment: yeah, I think they would be fine. I'm just not sure :|. even you did it and cant access the third or fourth partitions, you can bring them back . don't be afraid :) .